# Pass class as argument instead of object of it in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to make c# sql query builder.

So I have built some method which can be used as following.

`Query.Select("Order.OrderId").From("Order")`

I already have classes (models) generated from entity framework.

So is there a way, I can use their class name or/and their properties to be passed here as argument and get their name as string?

e.g. (notice no double quotes)

`Query.Select(Order.OrderId).From(Order)`

so far what I am using for time being is below.

`Query.Select($"{nameof(Order)}.{nameof(OrderId)}").From(nameof(Order))`

which as you can see is too ugly and destroys entire purpose of making sql query readable.

Reason I am not using EF queries is it gets too complex for complex queries. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Comment: Using generics and expressions you could create something like this `Query.Select<Order>(order => order.Id);`

Comment: @AnonymousCreator Do you consider using plain old `string` constants? For example, declare in the `Order` class the next constant `public const string OrderId = "Order.OrderId";` and the use it in the query `Query.Select(Order.OrderId)...`. In my opinion if you build query builder for internal usage then such approach will be easy to implement and easy for understanding.

Comment: Tudushev. ok. that I can do. because it will be one time and can be used multiple times. and how table name goes? for "From" clause?

Comment: For table name you should introduce field `public const string TableName = "Order"`. And usage will be the next: `Query.Select(Order.OrderId).From(Order.TableName)`.

Answer (score 0):

An example to use the class name or/and their properties to be passed as argument and get their name as string.

```
private static string abc<T>(string propertyName)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
    else
    {
        PropertyInfo columnProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        return typeof(T).Name + "." + columnProperty.Name;
    }
}


//An usage
Query.Select(abc<Order>("OrderId")).From(abc<Order>(""));
```